# Extract pattern from set of strings in R

Tags: r

I am looking to parse through a dataset and match it up with a tree I have already made in R. I am trying to simplify the tip labels to be matched up with my phylogenetic tree.

For instance from the "gi|399148998|gb|JN638572|" and simplifying that down to just "JN638572" (the accession number); and I need to do this 61 times (61 samples). Each of the accession numbers start at the same position as well.

```
## thanks for the data serban
set.seed(1)

mydat <- replicate(61, paste0(paste0(sample(letters,2), collapse=""),"|",
                              round(runif(1,1e8,1e9-1)),"|",
                              paste0(sample(letters,2), collapse=""),"|",
                              paste0(sample(LETTERS,2), collapse=""),
                              round(runif(1,1e6,1e7-1)),"|"))
head(mydat)
# [1] "gj|615568026|xf|XZ6947179|" "qb|285377117|er|JT5479293|" "sy|442031661|ux|FQ2129996|"
# [4] "gj|112051300|jv|IM6396092|" "me|844635986|rt|CS4701469|" "vq|804639485|on|UA5295070|"
```

Comment: did you try `strsplit("gi|399148998|gb|JN638572|", "[|]")`?

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot, you could copy and paste the output of `dput(head(listoftiplabels))`

Comment: You should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the question itself. No pictures of data.

Comment: Basically, `unlist(strsplit("gi|399148998|gb|JN638572|", "[|]"))[4]` might work

Comment: this should simply be `gsub('([A-Z]{2}\\d+)|.', '\\1', mydat)` if the desired part is always two capital letters followed by digits

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against using for loops in R when you can avoid it. R can perform whole-vector operations. For your particular instance, this ought to do it:

```
 library(stringr)
 #Generate some data: 
 mydat <- replicate(61, paste0(paste0(sample(letters,2), collapse=""),"|",
                                round(runif(1,1e8,1e9-1)),"|",
                                paste0(sample(letters,2), collapse=""),"|",
                                paste0(sample(LETTERS,2), collapse=""),
                                round(runif(1,1e6,1e7-1)),"|"))
head(mydat)
[1] "pg|451576916|kj|FV9562908|" "dt|707843618|sj|KZ3658708|" 
    "lb|507989738|lc|ML2309736|" "nb|448725577|fo|DW1950100|"
[5] "iv|337265231|us|CR5163970|" "ew|254260770|rw|LB2404167|"
 #Stuff you actually need:     
 results <- str_match(mydat, ".{2}\\|.*\\|.{2}\\|(.*)\\|")[,2]
 #Results:
 head(results)  
 [1] "FV9562908" "KZ3658708" "ML2309736" "DW1950100" "CR5163970" "LB2404167"
```

I am using regex, which stands for regular expressions. It would work with just `".*\\|(.*)\\|"` due to "greedy" interpreters, but I've made it needlessly complicated to make it easier to explain `.{Nr}` tells it to ignore `Nr` characters, and `.*` tells it to ignore as many characters as it takes to reach the next part of the pattern, namely `\\|`. The `|` is a special character and has to be "escaped" with `\\` so that the regex processor can take it literally instead. The parentheses are the "Capture group", i.e. what you want returned.

`str_match` is a function in the `stringr` library (which you may have to install with `install.packages("stringr")`), it returns in the first column the whole pattern, if a match is found, then the next column will be the first capture group. I'm returning the second column only by using the `[,2]` notation.